# No me funciona éste metodo mostrar() en una app Android para cambiar el texto de un TextView

Tags: android, app

Buenos días, tengo Android Studio 2.3.3 y el teléfono en el cuál estoy haciendo las pruebas es un Motorola Moto G primera generación; el cual tiene Android 5.1, mi app que es un simple contador lo hice para Android 5.0 o posteriores.
El problema es que no me funciona el método mostrar(), al pulsar los botones que ejecuten ése método, se detiene la app en mi teléfono.

Código del activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/displaycontador"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonsuma"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="78dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/displaycontador"
    android:onClick="suma"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonresta"
    android:layout_width="91dp"
    android:layout_height="78dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="135dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="-"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/botonsuma"
    android:onClick="resta"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botonreset"
    android:layout_width="66dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:text="Reset"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:onClick="reset"/>
```

Código del MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.gustavo.contador;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public int contador = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void suma(View vista) {
        contador++;
        mostrar();
    }

    public void resta(View vista) {
        contador--;
        mostrar();
    }

    public void reset(View vista) {
        contador = 0;
        mostrar();
    }

    public void mostrar() {
        TextView textor = new TextView(this);
        textor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaycontador);
        textor.setText(contador);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para que no sea tan dependiente de las imágenes. Si en el futuro las imágenes dejan de estar disponibles tu pregunta no servirá de nada. Además esta práctica dificulta que la gente pueda hacer pruebas al no poder copiar el código.

Comment: Por favor remplaza las imagenes por bloques de código. Pon el dump del error. Otra recomendación, el título de la pregunta debe ser más descriptivo que "no me funciona este metodo..."

Comment: en el activity_main.xml donde esta definido displayContador??
edita la pregunta y pega el codigo que asi entendemos

Comment: Lo has solucionado ya?

Comment: Ya está solucionado, ¿algún otro comenbtario acerca la publicación de la pregunta para no volver a cometer los mismos errores? (He editado al pregunta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución, debes convertir el valor de tipo int a String:

```
TextView textor;
textor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayContador);
textor.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces:

```
TextView textor = new TextView(this);
textor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayContador);
```

podrías hacer:

```
TextView textor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayContador);
```

Aunque dudo que ahí te de el fallo.

Lo que no puedes hacer es pasarle un entero al setText de un TextView, tienes que pasarle texto.
Para no modificar el tipo de contador puedes hacerlo así:

```
textor.setText(""+contador);
```

NOTA: La próxima vez que hagas una pregunta es mejor que pongas el código en texto y no en imagen, ya que así podremos copiarlo y ejecutar nosotros el código para ver lo que falla.

Answer (score 0):

Antes que nada asegura que el `TextView` con id `displaycontador` se encuentra dentro de `activity_main.xml` ya que si no existe, esto puede provocar un error al llamar el método.

---

Mencionas que al llamar este método se cierra tu aplicación:

```
public void mostrar(){
  TextView textor = new TextView(this);
  textor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaycontador);
  textor.setText(contador);
}
```

y obtienes el siguiente mensaje de error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x

Aquí tienes 2 detalles, el primero es que no necesitas instanciar el TextView:

```
  TextView textor = new TextView(this);
```

esto porque ya estas buscando la referencia en el layout:

```
  textor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaycontador);
```

y el segundo detalle que provoca un error es:

```
textor.setText(contador);
```

al tratar de definir un entero, la vista trata de buscar un elemento con id definido en R.java el cual no existe, por esta razón tienes que asegurar definir en [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) un valor tipo String:

```
textor.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
```

---

Para que no tengas problemas, el método debe ser simplemente:

```
public void mostrar(){
  TextView textor = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.displaycontador);
  textor.setText(String.valueOf(contador));
}
```