# ¿Cómo transformar un string a un int o viceversa?

Tags: java, android

El código funciona para pasar `string`, pero ¿cómo puedo cambiar el código para que en vez de tomar un `string`, tome un `int` llamado `plata` de la base de datos y mostrarlo en un `TextView`? y si no, ¿cómo puedo transformar el `string` de `plata` a un `int`?

Intenté transformarlo pero siempre deja de funcionar la app.

Background plata

```
public class BackgroundWorkerPlata extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
MainActivity ob;
Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;
BackgroundWorkerPlata (Context ctx) {
context = ctx;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
String type = params[0];
String plata_url = "plata page example";
if(type.equals("plata")) {
    try {
        String plata = params[1];
        URL url = new URL(plata_url);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("plata","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(plata,"UTF-8");
        bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
        String result="";
        String line="";
        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
            result += line;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        return result;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Cargando dinero");
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
// alertDialog.setMessage(result);
// alertDialog.show();
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(result) && result.contentEquals("platita")) {
    ob.PlataET.setText(result.toString().replace(',', '\n'));
}
}



@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate (Void...values){
super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

setText que transforma al TextView

```
public void cambiarTextoUpdatePlata(View v) {
PlataET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.PlataET);
String plata = PlataET.getText().toString();
String type = "plata";
BackgroundWorkerPlata backgroundWorkerPlata = new BackgroundWorkerPlata(this);
backgroundWorkerPlata.execute(type, plata);


PlataET.setText("Tienes " + plata + " Pesos");
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para pasarle un int a un TextBox, tienes que pasarlo a string o formar una cadena con él. Tienes 2 opciones:

-Crear un string con el valor del entero:

```
int plata = 5;
String enteroTxt = plata + ""; //en enteroTxt ahora tenemos "5", un String.
```

-Formar una cadena a la hora de pasarlo al textbox:

```
int plata = 5;
textBox.setText(plata + "");
```

Otra cosa que te puede pasar, aunque dices que con string te funciona, es que intentas modificar algo de la interfaz desde otro hilo, igual te está dando una excepción por eso, aunque al funcionarte con cadenas no debería lanzar esa excepción.

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Cómo transformar un string a un int?

Para convertir un valor entero a String puedes usar el método [**Integer.parseInt()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

```
String valorString = "12";
int valorEntero = Integer.parseInt(valorString);
```

debes asegurar que el valor a convertir a String sea numérico de lo contrario tendrás la exception [**NumberFormatException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html)

> ¿Cómo transformar un int a un String?

Para realizar esto puedes usar el método [**String.valueOf()**](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int))

```
int valorEntero = 12;
String valorString = String.valueOf(valorEntero);
```

u otra opción valida que es concatenando un string vació.

```
int valorEntero = 12;
String valorString = ""+valorEntero;
```

---

Es importante comentar sobre el uso del método [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)), debes asegurar que el valor asignado sea tipo `CharSequence` , ya que de otra forma si es un valor entero, estarás intentando obtener un recurso del proyecto.

revisa esta respuesta:
[No me funciona éste metodo mostrar() en una app Android para cambiar el texto de un TextView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91255/no-me-funciona-%C3%A9ste-metodo-mostrar-en-una-app-android-para-cambiar-el-texto-de/91394#91394)

---

En el caso de tu proyecto, el valor de plata inicialmente no necesitas convertirlo a String:

```
String plata = PlataET.getText().toString();
...
...
PlataET.setText("Tienes " + plata + " Pesos");
```

Pero si requieres el valor a int puedes usar `Integer.parse()` :

```
int iPlata = Integer.parse(plata);
```

Answer (score 1):

Si como comentas, recibes un entero de la base de datos, para mostrarlo en un `TextView` puedes pasarlo a cadena y entonces mostrarlo con `setText()`. Puedes convertirlo usando un método de la clase `Integer` o un método de la clase `String`. Ambos reciben un entero en parámetro:

#### Pasar de Entero a Cadena

- La clase [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) cuenta con el método **[`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString--)**, el cual devuelve una cadena del valor pasado en parámetro.
- La clase [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) cuenta con el método **[`valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf-int-)**, el cual retorna una cadena del entero que recibe en parámetro.

Ejemplos con uno o con otro asumiendo que `plata` es un entero:

```
String strPlata = Integer.toString(plata);
textBox.setText(strPlata);
```

O bien:

```
String strPlata = String.valueOf(plata)
textBox.setText(strPlata);
```

---

#### Pasar de Cadena a Entero

Si por el contrario, el valor recibido es una cadena y quiere pasarse a entero. Se puede usar el método **[`parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-)** de la clase `Integer`:

```
int intPlata = Integer.parseInt(strPlata);
```