# Sumar dos edittext mientras se escribe, error Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

```
Tara = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTaras);
        Tara.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(Tara.getText().length() > 0 && Peso.getText().length() >0) {
                    double rPeso = Double.parseDouble((Peso.getText().toString()));
                    double rTara = Double.parseDouble((Tara.getText().toString()));
                    double resta = rPeso - rTara;
                    Preal.setText((int) resta);
                }else{
                    Preal.setText("");
                }

            }
        });
```

pero me marca error,

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x

alguien que me ayude a solucionarlo.

> Error!
>   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que error te marca?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo he adjuntado una imagen, ve!

Answer (score 3):

el metodo [`setText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) tiene una sobrecarga [`setText(int resource)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)) que recibe un int que es el id de un recurso tipo String y claramente el resultado de la resta no es el id de un recurso string. Convierte el valor int a String para asignarle el texto al TextView.

Cambia

```
 Preal.setText((int) resta);
```

A esto:

```
 int restaInt = (int) resta;
 Preal.setText(restaInt.toString());
```

Comment: la solución quedo así: 
String restaInt = String.valueOf((int) resta);
                    Preal.setText(restaInt.toString());

Comment: Eso mismo. La idea era pasarle un string no un int.;

Comment: Recuerda marcar la respuesta si era la que esperabas.

Answer (score 1):

Esto lo he visto preguntado en el sitio pero no encontré la pregunta,

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x

El problema se deriva al tratar de definir un entero mediante el método [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)), la vista, en este caso el `TextView`,  trata de buscar un elemento con id definido en R.java (un identificador de recurso) el cual en este caso no existe, por esta razón tienes que asegurar definir en [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) un valor tipo `String`:

```
// Preal.setText((int) resta);
Preal.setText(String.valueOf(resta));
```

**Actualización:**

Encontré la pregunta, sin embargo la respuesta marcada como correcta, no indica porque razón se obtiene el error:

[No me funciona éste metodo mostrar() en una app Android para cambiar el texto de un TextView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91255/no-me-funciona-%C3%A9ste-metodo-mostrar-en-una-app-android-para-cambiar-el-texto-de/91394#91394)